# In Angular2 find max value for two keys

Tags: angular

I am reading from a data file with about 500 entries like:

```
const LOCKERS: Locker[] = [
  { lockerNumber: 1, room: 'Ladies', size: 'Small'},
  { lockerNumber: 2, room: 'Ladies', size: 'Small'},
  { lockerNumber: 3, room: 'Ladies', size: 'Small'},
  { lockerNumber: 4, room: 'Ladies', size: 'Small'},
  { lockerNumber: 1, room: 'Ladies', size: 'Large'},
  { lockerNumber: 2, room: 'Ladies', size: 'Large'},
  { lockerNumber: 3, room: 'Ladies', size: 'Large'},
  { lockerNumber: 1, room: 'Gents', size: 'Small'},
  { lockerNumber: 2, room: 'Gents', size: 'Small'},
  { lockerNumber: 3, room: 'Gents', size: 'Small'},
  { lockerNumber: 1, room: 'Gents', size: 'Large'},
  { lockerNumber: 2, room: 'Gents', size: 'Large'},
  { lockerNumber: 3, room: 'Gents', size: 'Large'},
  { lockerNumber: 4, room: 'Gents', size: 'Large'}
];
```

My service is like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Locker } from './locker';
import { LOCKERS } from './mock-lockers';

@Injectable()
export class LockerService {
    getLockers() {
        return Promise.resolve(LOCKERS);
    }
}
```

And my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Locker } from './locker';
import { LockerService } from './locker.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app/app.locker.html',
  providers: [LockerService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'The lockerrooms';
  lockers: Locker[];
  ladiesSmall: number;
  ladiesLarge: number;
  gentsSmall: number;
  gentsLarge: number;

  constructor(
    private lockerService: LockerService

  ) { }

  getLockers() {
    this.lockerService.getLockers()
      .then( data => this.lockers = data)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLockers();
  }
}
```

I am looking for a way to get the maximum lockerNumber for each room-size combination. 
Excepted Result-

```
MaxLadiesSmall 4
MaxLadiesLarge 3
MaxGentsSmall 3
MaxGentsLarge 4
```

Answer (score 0):

For operations like this is perfect the **Lodash** library and its [chaining ability](http://lodash.com/docs#_). Also the code is pretty much readeble.

Try this:

```
var gentsSmallMaximum = _(LOCKERS)
    .filter(locker => locker.room === 'Gents' && locker.size === 'Small')
    .map(locker => locker.lockerNumber)
    .max();
```

Just import the library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

or you can use definitely typed if you want TypeScript version:

```
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/lodash
```

then Put this before your @Component, to force TypeScript to compile:

```
declare var _: any;
```

Comment: When I try to add this suggestion to my component and index.html I get an exception: ReferenceError: _ is not defined.

Comment: I tried the part "var gentsSmallMaximum..." both separate as in the ngOnOnit function.

Comment: Problem solved.
The lodash script now as **last** in my index.html.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that..Im glad it works now for you

Comment: If you dont have anything else, will you accept the answer?:)

Comment: I have nothing else on this point, so I accept the answer. ;-)

Comment: Just a quick hint http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)